# How to calculate the distance from all points in a 3d matrix to a plane in matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, 3d

This question is from [my last post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30418780/how-to-find-the-plane-of-intersection-betweeen-a-plane-and-a-3d-matrix),

But I will just focus on a particular part,

If I have a **3d matrix M**, 256*256*124,and a plane defined by 3 points that intersect the 3d matrix, **A,B,C**, how to find the distance of all points in M to the plane defined by A,B,C

Here is the suggestion I got,

```
[X Y Z] = meshgrid(1:256,1:256,1:124)
A = [X(:)';Y(:)';Z(:)'];
n = cross([coor_A-coor_B],[coor_B-coor_C]); %The norm vector of the plane
d = norm(mean([coor_A,coor_B,coor_C]),2); %The distance from origin to the plane
```

According to [Hesse normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesse_normal_form),

```
L = ((n*A)-d);    %The distance from all points in M to the plane
```

But all the values in L are huge, which indicates that no points are found on the intersection plane.

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: What does "points in a 3d matrix" mean? Points are in space, a matrix just stores numbers, how do they relate in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed one line on the Wikipedia page

[image: formula1]

where

[image: formula2]

So add this line

```
n0 = n / norm(n);
```

and change the final line to

```
L = ((n0*A)-d);
```

Comment: You could have posted the full solution